# Jenkins maven release goes to lib-snapshot repository

Tags: maven, jenkins, release, snapshot, maven-release-plugin

I am having setup where Jenkins is used to release maven project to artifactory. I see everything is working fine what maven release do like incrementing pom versions, creating tag but it is not uploading to lib-release repo instead it is uploading it to lib-snapshot repo.

I verified my settings.xml and saw it uses different ids for snapshot and release repo. What else can I check to fix this issue?

This is my settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--<settings.version>1.0.1</settings.version>-->
<!--<settings.region>IL</settings.region>-->
<!--<settings.type>server</settings.type>-->
<settings xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <servers>
    <server>
      <id>artifactory_server</id>
      <username>deploy_user</username>
      <password>xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</password>
    </server>
  </servers>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <snapshots />
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <id>artifactory-snapshots</id>
          <name>libs-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-snapshot</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <id>artifactory-release</id>
          <name>libs-release</name>
          <url>http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
      <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </releases>
          <id>central</id>
          <name>plugins-release</name>
          <url>http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/plugins-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
          </snapshots>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <name>plugins-snapshot</name>
          <url>http://artifactory.example.com/artifactory/plugins-snapshot</url>
        </pluginRepository>
      </pluginRepositories>
      <id>artifactory</id>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  <activeProfiles>
    <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
  </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's completely up to Maven and POM definitions.
By default every Jenkins run are threaten as Snapshots but you can control them by 
Repositories with

```
<snapshots>
   <enabled>false</enabled>
</snapshots>
```

And using maven-release-plugin https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/examples/prepare-release.html

Comment: I am already using maven release plugin which is deploying to libs-snapshot instead of libs-release when I perform a release. I have pasted my settings.xml file